# how to add object on top of array using upsertOne in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using upsertOne to add object to array but it goes at the end of an array. But i want latest object on the top of an array.

```
builder.addCase(getDeviceData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            devicesAdapter.upsertOne(state, action.payload);
        });
```

Note: I cant use any timestamp or name to sort this values

Comment: EntityAdapter normalices the state data, and you want to alter that normalization. I think it doesnt make sense. I would use EntityAdapter `sortComparer` function in combination with a  timestamp.

Comment: i dont have any timestamp to sort array